# Function does not read a CSV file with read.csv2

Tags: r

I have a problem in R using readcsv2.
On it's own it works like a charm:

```
excel_csv <- read.csv2("example.csv", header = FALSE)
```

But when I try the same thing in a function:

```
excelConvert <- function (df) {

  excel_csv <- read.csv2("df", header = FALSE)

}
```

I get the folowing error;

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
```

My working directory is correct so I really don't know why it won't read the file in the function

Comment: `excelConvert <- function (df) { read.csv2(file=df, header = FALSE) }; excel_csv <- excelConvert("example.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

What @jogo answered in his comment is that in the function `df` should *not* be quoted. The difference between

```
read.csv2(file = "df", header = FALSE)  # as written in your function
# and
read.csv2(file =  df,  header = FALSE)  # as jogo suggested
```

is that in the first line, the argument `file` gets the literal value "`df`". That is, the function looks for a file in your current working directory named "df".

In the second line, the argument `file` gets the value *stored in* the variable `df`, which you pass when you call the function `excelConvert`.